# read from pandas dataframe, find a text in other file and label it

Tags: python, pandas, text-mining

I have provided an updated solution to the following text pre-processing. I was stumbled into an issue to categorize a sentence either positive, negative or uncertain. I mean, I was not able to create a tuple that Naive Bayes requires for classification and prediction. My updated solution below provides not so efficient but easier way.

I am doing a text preprocessing for Naive Bayes Classifier//Sentiment. I have pandas data frame of data I generated

```
risk
uncertain
somewhere
cautious
assumptions
somewhat
random
```

I want to compare that list to for an example text

*"The market is uncertain. There is volatility. Investors need to be cautious. It is not just a random walk phenomena."*

What I want to do is:

From the list above compare find if the word exists in the text below and result like

```
"Text", "Label" 
"The market is uncertain." "uncertain"
"There is volatility.", "negative"
```

etc

any thoughts?

#### UPDATE: TEST SOLUTION TO CATEGORIZE

```
text = "It was the best article. In fact we have assume. Ints the fact's and worse?. presume. pending"

from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
word_tokenize_list = word_tokenize(text)
sent_tokenize_list=sent_tokenize(text)


for sentIndex, sentence in enumerate(sent_tokenize_list):
word_tokenize_list = word_tokenize(sentence)
for wordIndex, word in enumerate(word_tokenize_list):
    for j in negativeList():
        if j ==word:
            negativeSentence= sentence
            print "neg", negativeSentence
            break 
    for j in postiveList():
        if j ==word:
            positiveSentence= sentence
            print "posi", positiveSentence
            break 
    for j in uncerList():
        if j ==word:
            uncertainSentence= sentence
            print "uncer",uncertainSentence
            break
```

uncerList(), postiveList() and negativeList() are just a list of the words that I classify and positive, negative and uncertain.

I did not use the text blob I used to ask the question above. But that worked for me as well!

Comment: Maybe try nltk (natural language processing toolkit). You can the get the labels from the sentence using nltk.

Comment: I used it for tokenizing. But yes it was easier with these. I updated solution is not an efficient but works well